# R: Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : undefined exports:

Tags: r, github, rstudio

I have written a R package using Roxygen2 to create the help files and the NAMESPACE. When I go

```
install_github("mintUser/bedarfspruefung3")
```

I get the following output and error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘bedarfspruefungV03’ ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: KiSt, LST2014, MLSTJAHR, MOSONST, MRE4, MRE4ABZ, MRE4ALTE, MRE4JL, MRE4SONST, MSOLZ, MSONST, MST56, MVMT, MVSP, MZTABFB, SolZ, SozV, UP56, UPANTEIL, UPEVP, UPLSTLZZ, UPMLST, UPTAB14, UPVKV, UPVKVLZZ, bedarfspruefung2, leistungALGII2, rating
ERROR: loading failed
```

Roxygen built the NAMESPACE file properly:

```
# Generated by roxygen2 (4.0.2): do not edit by hand

export(KiSt)
export(LST2014)
export(MLSTJAHR)
export(MOSONST)
export(MRE4)
export(MRE4ABZ)
export(MRE4ALTE)
export(MRE4JL)
export(MRE4SONST)
export(MSOLZ)
export(MSONST)
export(MST56)
export(MVMT)
export(MVSP)
export(MZTABFB)
export(SolZ)
export(SozV)
export(UP56)
export(UPANTEIL)
export(UPEVP)
export(UPLSTLZZ)
export(UPMLST)
export(UPTAB14)
export(UPVKV)
export(UPVKVLZZ)
export(bedarfspruefung2)
export(leistungALGII2)
export(rating)
```

So anyone an idea what's wrong with the NAMESPACE? No function gets exported to the package environment - when I run `KiSt()` after `install_github` and `library()` I get: `Could not find function 'KiSt'`

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you use `<-` instead of `<<-` for function definition etc. in `R/*.R`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error arose by using `<<-` to define the functions. Thanks to @kohske for the hint!