# R CMD check fails with "undefined exports"

Tags: r, package, export, roxygen2

I'm trying to create an R package but I keep getting the error:

```
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: MCLE, defineFunctions, naiveMLE
```

when running `R CMD check` on my package.  I'm using `roxygen2`, and the three functions listed in the error message are the three with `@export` tags.  I've checked similar problems/solutions on stack overflow:

- [R: Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : undefined exports:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742778/r-error-in-namespaceexportns-exports-undefined-exports)
- [Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : undefined exports: ... Error: package or namespace load failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413109/error-in-namespaceexportns-exports-undefined-exports-error-package-or)
- [What does "Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : undefined exports" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697727/what-does-error-in-namespaceexportns-exports-undefined-exports-mean)

but none of these seem to resolve my problem (I'm not using `<<-`, I don't export any functions with a common help page, and the issue isn't with `ggplot2` or a different R package on CRAN).

I've built the package after deleting the `NAMESPACE` file, and it built successfully.  I've also confirmed that the package has the functions listed as "undefined," and I don't know what else to check!

Comment: `MCLE`, `defineFunctions` and `naiveMLE` are your own functions, right?

Comment: @Pascal Yes, exactly.  Sorry, I just now realized that I mentioned they have export tags but I should have noted that they are also functions in my package.

Answer (score 7):

I had a very similar problem. Did you check your .Rbuildignore file? 
It could be related to regular expression matches with the functions you want to export.

I was trying to exclude from the build the directory "HTLM_downloads" by putting the name inside .Rbuildignore. Unfortunately this does not work since it ignores every file containing the word "html" (HTML). Not even an `@export` solved the problem. I needed to anchor the expression by putting `^HTML_downloads$`.

You can easily exclude files and/or directory by using `devtools::use_build_ignore("file/dir you want to ignore")`.

Hope this helped

I'd like to thank @hadley for his kind and neat support

Comment: Thank you for this. I had "foo" in .Rbuildignore because I wanted to exclude a folder with that name, but it ended up masking a couple of exported functions that also had "foo" in the name. Writing "foo/" instead made sure .Rbuildignore ignored the folder and left the functions alone.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing ! I have been banging my head for 1 day+ on this...

Comment: I am sorry, if you find my answer correct, could you please accept it as it is and flag it? Thanks

Comment: Incredibly helpful! I had no idea that this could happen. I had a few custom regexpr for file extensions, which I guess caught all functions in my package. For me, I erased all patterns in the `.Rbuildignore` file and explicitly named the files and paths that I wanted to ignore.

Comment: Thanks! Can you check the answer as the solution pls.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and my brand new package had my /R folder in `.Rbuildignore` (smh). Removed it from the file and all builds nicely.

Comment: @random_forest_fanatic can you please flag the answer as correct if it solved your problem? It's been a while now. Thanks